# run macro by enter key

Tags: vba, excel

Why does the following macro run on all pages while it should run only on the page that was written in its change sheet.

Is there a way to correct it?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$Q$3" Then
        Call GoToAccount
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Show us `GoToAccount`, it could be what's actually running on every worksheet

Comment: no GoToAccount is not running.

Comment: You could try and add: `Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate`, replace Sheet1 with your name. But I think it's more likely that `GoToAccount`, refer to other worksheets...

Comment: @m.vesali - what do you mean `no GoToAccount is not running`?  You have it right in your example!  It runs every time `Q3` is changed on the this worksheet.  Perhaps it would help if you [edit] your question to add some more information about your problem.  See [ask] as well as [mcve].